# Enabling Time on raster layers in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: geotiff-tiff, arcgis-pro, time

I have several raster layers (all tiffs) in ArcGIS Pro and I would like to enable *Time* on each layer. This was straightforward in all versions of ArcMap 10 but not so here it would seem.

As instructed by this [article on ArcGIS Onine](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/time/set-the-time-properties-on-data.htm), I right clicked the layer and clicked on  *Properties*, however *Time* wasn't in the list of properties (it is in both the article and in Youtube videos I've looked at).

How do I configure *Layer Properties* so that I can enable *Time* on my layers?

Comment: I may be wrong but time is not a property of a raster dataset, see [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/time/how-time-is-supported-in-spatial-data.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/time/set-the-time-properties-on-data.htm) you link to, you can enable time for [feature classes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/feature-classes/feature-classes.htm), [mosaic datasets](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/mosaic-datasets.htm) or [NetCDFs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/multidimensional/what-is-netcdf-data.htm).  Your tifs are rasters and not one of those types.

You can however, put your tiffs into a mosaic dataset then enable time on that.